# Check words definitions using iBooks App Dictionary

Tags: ios, dictionary, sdk, safari, ibooks

I see that iBooks App and Safari have a built-in dictionary. **Can I access this dictionary /Words definitions by my own app?**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I dont think thats very much possible. You can use [UITextChecker](http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextChecker_Class/Reference/Reference.html) or you can use some open source sdks like [Lexicontext](http://www.lexicontext.com/). Also may be you can link to some online dictionaries.